# difference in using kill -9 with kill SIGUSR2

Tags: shell, kill-process, sigkill

what is difference in operation using kill command format, in what scenario which one to used.

```
kill -9 process-id
kill SIGUSR2 process-id
```

Comment: `kill -l` gives you the signals. SIGUSR2 (12) is completely different from SIGKILL (9). Other than that, depends heavily on how the application handles signals, i.e. SIGUSR2. For example you could use `signal` (in C) to intercept SIGUSR2 and perform whatever task you want.

Comment: `kill SIGUSR2 pid` looks like a kill syntax error to me. You may be interested in http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/signal.7.html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to send `SIGUSR2` to a process, you would use either:

```
kill -SIGUSR2 $pid
kill -USR2 $pid
kill -10 $pid   # This will vary with platform
```

If you want to send `SIGKILL` to a process, you would use either:

```
kill -SIGKILL $pid
kill -KILL $pid
kill -9 $pid
```

Not sure how to answer your question about "which scenario".  If you want to send `USR2`, then you use one of the former 3 commands.  If you want to send `KILL`, you use one of the latter.  You typically want to avoid using `KILL`, as a process that receives a `KILL` cannot clean up after itself.  On the other hand, a lot of software is written poorly and can only be terminated via `SIGKILL`.  It is usually considered more polite to send `TERM`, then wait some period of time before sending `TERM` a second time, then wait again before sending `KILL`.  `USR2` is typically only useful for programs that are expecting it and will respond in some useful way.  If the program is not expecting the signal and no action has been taken to ignore it, the default behavior is to terminate.

Note that the specific signal number of SIGUSR2 varies.  Depending on the platform, it may be 10, 12, 31, and probably many other values.  It is best to avoid setting the value explicitly.  The only signal numbers which are [standardized](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/kill.html) are 1,2,3,6,9,14, and 15, so 9 is always `SIGKILL`, but `SIGUSR2` may (and does!) vary.